# d3 - hex grid - by country (topojson geojson)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, meteor, geojson, topojson

I would like to create a hex grid that is shaped by countries using d3 and topojson (using Meteor to power it all).

My approach is to generate the country from data using naturalearth.org maps, then creating a hex grid for each country (the rule of thumb here is if the center of the hex is not within the country then it doesn't get rendered), and then remove the country (since all I want is the hex grids for each country). Finally, I'd like to outline the borders with the hex grids generated.

I have no issues with generating the countries based on the maps available at naturalearth. My biggest issue is drawing the hexes on top of the map and getting them to conform to each country. What data can I use to determine if the center of a hex is within a country?

I am using the hexbin plugin.

Comment: I'm on the lookout for something similar. Did you ever solve this?